# How to combine various armatures?

Tags: rigging, armature

I put together an armature for a four legged creature, but I had to make each leg armature separate. I now want to combine them into one armature. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Do you want to keep the four legs for deformation of the mesh and have another one to control the movement?  I guess you don't want to let the legs move synchronously (This wouldn't look like walking). Could you explain a bit more how it should move.

Answer (score 8):

1. Select all the leg armatures, in Object mode.
2. Go to the Object menu, >> **Join** (or Ctrl + J).

That said, I hope you didn't weight paint anything yet, because if so, you may have to rename some of your bones' VGs.

Comment: This technique combines the formerly separate armature objects into a single armature object consisting of four discrete sets of bones. If your intent is to combine them into a single set of connected bones, you'll have to make the connections manually after you follow the procedure  Mike described.

Comment: Thanks @Mike Belanger. As usual the solution is super simple, hehe. You really saved my life :). Upvoteded.

Comment: How do you make the connections manually? I don't see an option in the "Bone" context -> "Relations" -> "Parent" to set the parent to a bone of another armature.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine the bones into a single armature using the method Mike outlined. But while the four leg armatures are all part of the same armature, they are not physically connected. To connect them together into a single entity, you will have to construct the desired connecting bones yourself.